# How can i multiply only items in list which has some common numbers at the end?

Tags: python

I have a list

```
sample_list=[-1.0, -1.0, 1.25999, 3999.0, 6999.0, 3777.0, 6888.0, 3999.0, 3999.0, 6999.0, 6999.0, 8999.0, 14.75999]
```

I have to find only those items which contains "999"
then trim "999" from that item and then multiply with 30.

Example : if 1.25999 is the item then removing "999" ->1.25 then multiply it with 30 resulting 37.5

I have tried following code snippet:

```
sample_list=[-1.0, -1.0, 1.25999, 3999.0, 6999.0, 3777.0, 6888.0, 3999.0, 3999.0, 6999.0, 6999.0, 8999.0, 14.75999]
for i in sample_list:
    if "999" in i:
        i = i.translate(None, '999')
        i=i*30
print(sample_list)
```

I am getting error : TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable

Comment: Do you want to remove `999` at the end only? or at any decimal places in the number? To resolve the `TypeError` you can first convert i to string then use membership check: `if "999" in str(i)`

Comment: at any decimal point i have remove 999.

Comment: And do you want to keep the numbers that doesn't have `999` in it, how do you want to go about it?

Comment: Yes keep the numbers as it is that doesn't have 999.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in one line, thus also modifying the list itself:

```py
sample_list = [-1.0, -1.0, 1.25999, 3999.0, 6999.0, 3777.0,
               6888.0, 3999.0, 3999.0, 6999.0, 6999.0, 8999.0, 14.75999]
sample_list = [float(str(i).replace('999', ''))*30 if '999' in str(i) else i for i in sample_list]
print(sample_list)
```

What it does:
In order to check if a number is within another number, we must first convert them to strings since that way you can use the `in` keyword.
Next we check if 999 is in the number.
If it is, we remove the 999, convert it back to a number and multiply by 30.
If it isn't, we just enter the number regularly.

This gives us a list without 999s and multiplied where it was removed.

If you'd like to know more about the one-liner format, they're called list comprehensions [and you can read more about them here.](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Comment: This will only remove 999 after decimal point .

Comment: @Maya No. It will remove 999 from anywhere that it occurs

Comment: It won't remove 999 which has a `.` in the middle - but that's a different case than you described.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate the numbers, convert to string then check if `999` is there if yes replace it by empty string value then finally convert to float and multiply by 30, you can accomplish it using List Comprehension. And to avoid multiple conversions, you can use [named expression `:=`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/#syntax-and-semantics) if you have python 3.9+:

```py
>>>[float(v.replace("999", ""))*30 if "999" in (v:=str(x)) else x for x in sample_list]
# Output
[-1.0, -1.0, 37.5, 90.0, 180.0, 3777.0, 6888.0, 90.0, 90.0, 180.0, 180.0, 240.0, 442.5]
```

Comment: This is exactly what @Adid posted

Comment: @TalhaTayyab updated the answer. I had already written the previous answer but was waiting for some confirmation from OP for the queries I had which I had mentioned in the comments in question

Comment: Good job @ThePyGuy!

Comment: @ThePyGuy Minor point. The walrus operator is available from 3.8+. Also, the OP's question talks about "common numbers at the end" whereas this code will affect all numbers with '999' anywhere in their string representation

Answer (score 0):

The question mentions "common numbers at the end". Therefore, to isolate those values one could do this:

```
sample_list = [-1.0, -1.0, 1.25999, 3999.0, 6999.0, 3777.0, 6888.0, 3999.0, 3999.0, 6999.0, 6999.0, 8999.0, 14.75999]
output = [float(e[:-3])*30 if (e := str(n)).endswith('999') else n for n in sample_list]
print(output)
```

**Output:**

```
[-1.0, -1.0, 37.5, 3999.0, 6999.0, 3777.0, 6888.0, 3999.0, 3999.0, 6999.0, 6999.0, 8999.0, 442.5]
```